# PySpark - Sequential Counts with Pandas UDF

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column dataset that has increasing values any columns for the same  month, and then resets for the next month.

```
+----------+------+-----------+----+-----------+------------+
|      Date|column|column_2   |co_3|column_4   |column_5    |
+----------+------+-----------+----+-----------+------------+
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         14|           0|
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         14|           0|
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         18|           0|
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         19|           0|
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         20|           0|
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         26|           0|
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         60|           0|
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         63|           0|
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         78|           0|
|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         90|           0|
+----------+------+-----------+----+-----------+------------+
```

The problem is that their date is always the same, so I want to do some sort of counting up, and then resetting the count when we approach a different day.

I've written a Pandas UDF Function:

```
@pandas_udf('int', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def get_counts_up(v):
  prev = None
  series = []
  count = 0
  for i in v:
    if prev != i:
      count = 0
      prev = i
    series.append(count)
    count += 1
  return pd.Series(series)
```

However, the output does not seem to be continuous:

```
sdf.filter(sdf.Date == "2016-12-14").sort("Date_Count").show()

+------------+----------+------+-----------+----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+----------+-----+----------+
|Date_Convert|      Date|column|column_____|col_|column_____|column______|Date_Year|Date_Month|Date_Day|Date_Epoch|count|Date_Count|
+------------+----------+------+-----------+----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+----------+-----+----------+
|  2016-12-14|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         14|           0|     2016|        12|      14|1481673600|14504|         0|
|  2016-12-14|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         18|           0|     2016|        12|      14|1481673600|14504|         0|
|  2016-12-14|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         14|           0|     2016|        12|      14|1481673600|14504|         1|
|  2016-12-14|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         18|           0|     2016|        12|      14|1481673600|14504|         1|
|  2016-12-14|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         18|           0|     2016|        12|      14|1481673600|14504|         2|
|  2016-12-14|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         14|           0|     2016|        12|      14|1481673600|14504|         2|
|  2016-12-14|2016-12-14|     0|          0|   0|         14|           0|     2016|        12|      14|1481673600|14504|         3|
+------------+----------+------+-----------+----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+----------+-----+----------+
```

Which is to be expected, because I guess the dataframe is split off into different machines (a few on DataBrick's community edition), and each have their own array to maintain.

Is there a way to perform a sequential counting up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combination of `Window` and `row_number` functions should solve it for you. I have used all of the columns for ordering as you've said

> > dataset that has increasing values any columns for the same month...

but you can use only one column or many which has the increasing values.

```
from pyspark.sql import window as w
windowSpec = w.Window.partitionBy("Date").orderBy("column", "column_2", "co_3", "column_4", "column_5")

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.withColumn('inc_count', f.row_number().over(windowSpec)).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+----------+------+--------+----+--------+--------+---------+
|Date      |column|column_2|co_3|column_4|column_5|inc_count|
+----------+------+--------+----+--------+--------+---------+
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |14      |0       |1        |
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |14      |0       |2        |
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |18      |0       |3        |
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |19      |0       |4        |
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |20      |0       |5        |
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |26      |0       |6        |
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |60      |0       |7        |
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |63      |0       |8        |
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |78      |0       |9        |
|2016-12-14|0     |0       |0   |90      |0       |10       |
+----------+------+--------+----+--------+--------+---------+
```